# How to zoom camera with HUD in opengl/pyglet?

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, pyglet

I am making a 2d strategy game in pyglet and implemented camera movement using the glTranslatef function:

```
def background_motion(dt):
    if stars.left:
        pyglet.gl.glTranslatef(15, 0, 0)
        stars.translation[0] += 15
    if stars.right:
        pyglet.gl.glTranslatef(-15, 0, 0)
        stars.translation[0] -= 15
    if stars.up:
        pyglet.gl.glTranslatef(0, -15, 0)
        stars.translation[1] -= 15
    if stars.down:
        pyglet.gl.glTranslatef(0, 15, 0)
        stars.translation[1] += 15
```

And made the HUD stay in position like this:

```
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    stars.image.draw()
    for s in game.ships:
        s.draw()
    pyglet.gl.glTranslatef(-stars.translation[0], -stars.translation[1], 0)

    #HUD Start
    overlay.draw(stars.image.x,stars.image.y,game.ships,stars.scale,stars.image.width)
    if game.pause:
        pause_text.draw()
    #HUD End

    pyglet.gl.glTranslatef( stars.translation[0], stars.translation[1], 0)
```

I tried a similar aproach when it comes to zooming and while the zooming worked the HUD was also scaled:

```
def on_mouse_scroll(x, y, scroll_x, scroll_y):
    if scroll_y > 0:
        stars.scale += 0.01

    elif scroll_y < 0:
        stars.scale -= 0.01

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    pyglet.gl.glScalef(stars.scale,stars.scale, 0, 1)
    stars.image.draw()
    for s in game.ships:
        s.draw()
    scale_reverse = 1 + (1 - stars.scale)
    pyglet.gl.glScalef(scale_reverse, scale_reverse, 0, 1)
    pyglet.gl.glTranslatef(-stars.translation[0], -stars.translation[1], 0)

    #HUD Start
    overlay.draw(stars.image.x,stars.image.y,game.ships,stars.scale,stars.image.width)
    if game.pause:
        pause_text.draw()
    #HUD End

    pyglet.gl.glTranslatef( stars.translation[0], stars.translation[1], 0)
    pyglet.gl.glScalef(stars.scale, stars.scale, 0, 1)
    stars.scale = 1
```

How can I do it so that the HUD isn't scaled?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Ups, forgot sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note, that drawing by [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences and the fixed function matrix stack and fixed is deprecated since decades.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

Anyway, I recommend to use [`glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml), to store the matrix, before the HUD is drawn and to restore it after.
So you can set the identity matrix by [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) before you draw the HUD.
It would be even possible, to use a completely different (translation and scale) matrix for the HUD:

```py
#HUD Start
pyglet.gl.glPushMatrix()
pyglet.gl.glLoadIdentity()

overlay.draw(stars.image.x,stars.image.y,game.ships,stars.scale,stars.image.width)
if game.pause:
    pause_text.draw()

pyglet.gl.glPopMatrix()
#HUD End
```